longest element in set $W_\gamma wW_\nu vW_\mu$
Let $(W,S)$ be a finite Coxeter group, $W_\gamma,W_\nu,W_\mu$ be three parabolic subgroups. For $w,v\in W$,
let us consider the set $W_\gamma wW_\nu vW_\mu$. Does there exixt a unique longest element (for Bruhat order) of this set?
Remark: It is true for $W_\nu=W$ or $W_\nu={id}.$

Is this maybe a "triple coset"?  In my mind, a "double coset" would be the case $v=id$ and $V_\mu={id}$.  I read your question without actually parsing the math symbols, saw "longest element of double cosets" and was about to give you a reference for the result that you apparently already know.  But happily I read the question more carefully before actually answering.  :)

@NathanReading, thanks for your comments! Here the "double cosets" I means is the set $W_\gamma wW_\nu vW_\mu$ . Maybe the title is misleading, sorry.
